# Cronjob is not running Properly

Tags: cron

I have written a cron job as follow:

```
45  08/3 * * *  bin/run.sh job
```

it is getting started at 8:45 but Once it finished. Its not starting again .

Comment: what do you exactly want to do? What is your schedule? Do you want to run daily at 8:45 am ??

Comment: No I want to run it after every 3 hrs starting from 8:45

Comment: i think it should be `45 8/3 * * * /bin/run.sh`. make sure path to your script.

Comment: Its running only once a day That is the issue

Comment: Your syntax is correct. the problem is there are two spaces between 45 and 08. make it `45 08/3 * * * /bin/run.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run every 3 hours, starting at 3:45

`45  */3 * * * bin/run.sh job`

If you're trying to skip the hours between midnight and 8:45,

`45 8,11,14,17,20,23 * * * bin/run.sh job`